# How to monitor the pausing state of Activity before it paused?

Tags: android

I want to monitor the pausing state of Activity before it completely enter into paused state, is the method to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do action before super.onPause()

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    //do Action here
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: is any other method invoked before onPause() was invoked except onUserLeaveHint() for it can't be invoked in some cases?